# Create a plain message box that disappears after a few seconds in Java

Tags: java, swing

I wonder what is the best approach to make a JOptionPane style plain message box disappear after being displayed for a set amount of seconds.

I am thinking to fire up a separate thread (which uses a timer) from the main GUI thread to do this, so that the main GUI can carry on processing other events etc. But how do I actually make the message box in this separate thread disappear and terminate the thread properly. Thanks.

Edit: so this is what I come up with by following the solutions posted below

```
package util;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class DisappearingMessage implements ActionListener
{
    private final int ONE_SECOND = 1000;

    private Timer timer;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel msgLabel;

public DisappearingMessage (String str, int seconds) 
{
frame = new JFrame ("Test Message");
msgLabel = new JLabel (str, SwingConstants.CENTER);
msgLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));

timer = new Timer (this.ONE_SECOND * seconds, this);
// only need to fire up once to make the message box disappear
timer.setRepeats(false);
}

/**
 * Start the timer
 */
public void start ()
{
// make the message box appear and start the timer
frame.getContentPane().add(msgLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
frame.setVisible(true);

timer.start();
}

/**
 * Handling the event fired by the timer
 */
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
{
// stop the timer and kill the message box
timer.stop();
frame.dispose();
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
DisappearingMessage dm = new DisappearingMessage("Test", 5);
dm.start();
}
}
```

Now the question is that, as i cam going to create multiple instances of this class throughout the course of the interaction between the user and the main GUI, I wonder whether the dispose() method cleans up everything properly every time. Otherwise, I may end up with accumulating lots of redundant objects in memory. thanks.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose\(\), shall I take that all instances involved in the message box would be cleaned up?

Comment: @mKorbel: could you please elaborate?

Comment: trashgod (little bit crypted) What does your profiler say? ... about method finalize (or detailed described in API)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in your situation, you can't use any of `JOptionPane` static methods (`showX...`). You have to create a `JOptionPane` instance instead, then create a `JDialog` from it and show that `JDialog` yourself. Once you have `JDialog`, you can force its visibility.

```
// Replace JOptionPane.showXxxx(args) with new JOptionPane(args)
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(...);
final JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog("title");
Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        dialog.setVisible(false);
        // or maybe you'll need dialog.dispose() instead?
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

I haven't tried it so I can't guarantee that it works but I think it should ;-)

Of course, here `Timer` is `javax.swing.Timer`, as someone else already mentioned, thus you're sure the action will run in the EDT and you won't have any problem with creating or terminating your own `Thread`.

Comment: So just to confirm, while the JOptionPane instance is being shown on the screen for DELAY amount of time, the main GUI is still responsive in this case? In addition, when the dialog disappear (gets disposed), the main GUI thread is not affected in any way? Thanks.

Comment: @skyork to make this solution allow you for interaction you have to call 
  `dialog.setModal(false);` before calling setVisible(), as the dialog created using JOptionPane is set to modal by default.

Answer (score 1):

[Timers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) have their own threads. I think what you probably should do is create a new `Timer` (or, preferably, make one that you reuse till you don't need it any more), schedule a task that will ask for the message box to disappear and then have that task [add another task to the event queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29), which will remove the message box.

There might be a better way though.

In addition:
Yes, using `javax.swing.timer` would probably be better. The reason I talk about using two tasks in the above is that I assume you will have to execute your hiding method inside of the AWT thread to avoid certain subtle race issues that might arise. If you use `javax.swing.Timer` you're already executing in the AWT thread, so that point becomes moot.

Comment: why do you need two tasks here? What do you mean by having another task to 'remove the message box'?